# Autodesk design automation Revit , text file as input

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-designautomation

The Revit API I developed, take a text file as input.
the text file looks like as below......

1.002, 20,502, 21.706

12.502, 5,502, 7.706

21.002, 15,502, 14.706

.....................

.....................
(The values are not correct.just imaginary. I am just showing how my text file looks like)

I am basically reading the text data as input.
Now if I want to convert the same API as Design automation API, I guess I will not be able to use "text file" as input.

My question is, what should be file type of input file, if it is consisted of 3d point coordinates as described above.
Should it be Json? If it need to be json, then how I should write it for point coordinates? or any other suggestion for file type will be a big help.

If there is any example code, will be a big help.

In the list for supported input file format, txt file is not included.

If I write a Json file, then please give me some clue, how should I arrange it and read the file for Revit.

Many thanks in advance.

T

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your query.

The slightly more complex question is how to generate multiple output files.

That is answered by the article
on [How to generate dynamic number of output with Design Automation for Revit V3](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3).

In passing, it also mentions multiple input files, saying:

"... For the zipped input file, it's well documented at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-post-workitem/, but for the output zipped result, it's not so clear..."

Trying to follow that link, I note that it is out of date.

The updated link is:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/

Looking at the [additional notes on input arguments](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/#additional-notes), I see the instructions on how to pass JSON input data directly in the workitem itself.

I would assume that you can also use a different prefix instead of `data:application/json` such as `data:application/text` to pass in the data in its current form.

Please try that out and let us know how it works for you.

Alternatively, you can just stay on the safe side and convert your text data to JSON format.

There are innumerable ways of doing so.

The most minimalistic and simple would look like this:

```
    [1.002, 20,502, 21.706,
    12.502, 5,502, 7.706,
    21.002, 15,502, 14.706,
    ...]
```

That represents on single array of doubles.

A slightly more structured approach might be to pass in an array of triples of doubles like this:

```
    [[1.002, 20,502, 21.706],
    [12.502, 5,502, 7.706],
    [21.002, 15,502, 14.706],
    ...]
```

As you see, it is not hard.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many Thanks Jeremy. All nice help. I am going through it. I will make it Json, for the safe side :)